# clase rectangulo, problema Deitel establecer y obtener

Tags: java, constructor

Me piden crear una clase rectangulo con longitud y anchura.

> 8.4 (*Clase Rectángulo*) Cree una clase llamada Rectángulo con los atributos longitud y anchura, cada uno con un valor predeterminado de
>   `1`. Debe tener métodos para calcular el perímetro y el área del rectángulo. Debe tener métodos *establecer* y *obtener* para longitud
>   y anchura. Los métodos *establecer* deben verificar que la longitud y
>   anchura sean números de punto flotante mayores de `0,0`, y menores de
>   `20,0`. Escriba un programa para probar la clase Rectángulo.

¿En qué estoy mal?

```
public class DeitelClaseRectangulo882Evaluacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DeitelClasePrueba rectangulo = new  DeitelClasePrueba(2.0, 3.0 );
        System.out.printf("%d", rectangulo );
        //System.out.printf("%d", rectangulo );
        //rectangulo.obtenerLongitud();
        //rectangulo.obtenerAnchura();
    } // main
    class DeitelClasePrueba
    {
        private double longitud;
        private double anchura;
        public DeitelClasePrueba()
        {
            longitud = 1;
            anchura = 1;
        }
        // constructor con valor predeterminado de 1 
        public DeitelClasePrueba( double longitudPrueba, double anchuraPrueba ) 
        {
            longitud = longitudPrueba;
            anchura = anchuraPrueba;
        }
        public double calculaPerimetro() 
        {

            return 2 *( anchura + longitud );
        }
        public double calcularArea()
        {
            return anchura * longitud;
        }
        // metodo establecer debe verificar que longitud sea numero flotante
        // mayores de 0.0 y menores de 20.0
        public void establecerLongitud()
        {
            if ( longitud >= 0.0 && longitud < 20.0 )
                longitud = longitudPrueba;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "la longitud debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");
        } // establecerLongitud
        public void establecerAnchura()
        {
            if ( anchura >= 0.0 && anchura < 20.0 )
                anchura = anchuraPrueba;
            else 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "el ancho debe de ser > 0 < 20 ");  
        }
        public double obtenerLongitud()
        {
            return longitud;
        }

        public double obtenerAnchura()
        {
            return anchura;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Hola @Gerardo , el enunciado de tu pregunta hubiese sido mejor que copiaras directamente y no con imágenes.

Comment: gracias por sus consejos que por cierto seguiré en otras dudas, les agradezco a todos por el apoyo

Answer (score 1):

El error que salta es por que dentro del metodo main que es estático no puedes hacer referncia a la clase interna (creo que es la traducción de inner class) DeitelClasePrueba, ya que como te dice el error, desde un contexto estático no puedes referenciar un elemento no estático.

Tal cual está el código te funcionará si simplemente marcas la clase DeitelClasePrueba como estática.

Adicionalmente, tambien esta el problema que refieren @dev-joel y @alexis-rodrigez , falta el parámetro con el valor a establecer para longitud y anchura.

## Código

```
public class DeitelClaseRectangulo882Evaluacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DeitelClasePrueba rectangulo = new  DeitelClasePrueba(2.0, 3.0 );
        System.out.printf("%d", rectangulo );
    }

    // este static es el que habilita que puedas usar la clase desde el main
    static class DeitelClasePrueba
    {
        ...contenido...

        // metodo establecer debe verificar que longitud sea numero flotante
        // mayores de 0.0 y menores de 20.0
        public void establecerLongitud(float longitudPrueba)
        {
            if ( longitud >= 0.0 && longitud < 20.0 )
                longitud = longitudPrueba;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "la longitud debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");
        } 

        // establecerLongitud
        public void establecerAnchura(float anchuraPrueba)
        {
            if ( anchura >= 0.0 && anchura < 20.0 )
                anchura = anchuraPrueba;
            else 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "el ancho debe de ser > 0 < 20 ");  
        }
    }
}
```

## Nota

- Como te sugiere @dev-joel si separas DitelClasePrueba en un fichero separado con el mismo nombre, no tendrías este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas consideraciones para mejorar su código y sus errores que probablemente está presentando `variables indefinidas` , `acceso a la clase DeitelClasePrueba`

- Separar las clases de la clase Principal , aunque Java no lo prohíbe , no es un buena practica
- Cuando habla de valores predeterminados es que el `constructor` vacío debe inicializar los atributos a 1
- Cuando le solicitan métodos `obtener(get)` y `establecer(set)` se refieren a los `getters` y `setters` que deben tener todas sus clases

Su clase Rectángulo quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
public class Rectangulo {
private double longitud;
private double anchura;

public Rectangulo(double longitud, double anchura) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
    this.anchura = anchura;
}

public Rectangulo() {
    this.longitud=1;
    this.anchura=1;
}

 /* Aquí van los Métodos calcular Area y Perimetro*/

public double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}
 public double getAnchura() {
    return anchura;
} 
/* Métodos Set incluida su Verificación */
public void setLongitud(double longitud) {
    if ( longitud > 0.0 && longitud < 20.0 )
        this.longitud = longitud;
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(
        "la longitud debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");
}

public void setAnchura(double anchura) {
    if (anchura > 0.0 && anchura < 20.0 )
        this.anchura = anchura;
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(
        "la Anchura debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Rectangulo{" + "longitud=" + longitud + ", anchura=" + anchura + '}';
 }
}
```

Y en su Archivo Principal (Main) tendría

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  /* Constructor sin Parametros , atributos igual a 1 */
  Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo();
  rect.setAnchura(-12.2);/*Exception menor a 0*/
  rect.setLongitud(12.2);/* Valor aceptado */
  System.out.println(rect.calcularArea()); /* Obtener Area*/
  System.out.println(rect.calculaPerimetro());/* Obtener Perimetro*/
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion soy nuevo en esto, gracias. una pregunta en el segundo constructor las referencias "this" donde asignas en 1 longitud y anchura se refieren a los del primer constructor ?

Comment: `this` hace referencia a los atributos de la clase.  Para ello se hace uso de la palabra reservada `this` así que cuando en tu clase principal escribas `Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo ()` tus atributos tendrán valor 1 por defecto.  Sin pasarle parámetros.

Comment: ya quedo listo pero hay algo que no me queda claro,

Comment: cuando crea la nueva instancia DeitelClasePrueba rect1 = new DeitelClasePrueba(); me dice un error que dice " non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Es por la definición de tu clase en tu mismo archivo. Deberían tener separado esa  clase Rectangulo en otro archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que no le pusiste la variable de parametro en los metodos establecer.

```
public class DeitelClaseRectangulo882Evaluacion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    DeitelClasePrueba rectangulo = new  DeitelClasePrueba();

    rectangulo.establecerLongitud(22);
    rectangulo.establecerAnchura(4);

    System.out.println(rectangulo.obtenerLongitud() );
    System.out.println( rectangulo.obtenerAnchura() );
    System.out.println("Perimetro "+rectangulo.calculaPerimetro() );
    System.out.println("Area: "+rectangulo.calcularArea() );
    //rectangulo.obtenerLongitud();
    //rectangulo.obtenerAnchura();



  } // main 

}

class DeitelClasePrueba
{

private float longitud;
private float anchura;


public DeitelClasePrueba()
{
    longitud = 1;
    anchura = 1;

}


public float calculaPerimetro() 
{

    return 2 *( anchura + longitud );
}

public float calcularArea()
{
    return anchura * longitud;
}

// metodo establecer debe verificar que longitud sea numero flotante
// mayores de 0.0 y menores de 20.0
public void establecerLongitud(float longitud)
{
    if ( longitud >= 0.0 && longitud < 20.0 )
        this.longitud = longitud;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "la longitud debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");
} // establecerLongitud

public void establecerAnchura(float anchura)
{
    if ( anchura >= 0.0 && anchura < 20.0 )
        this.anchura = anchura;
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "el ancho debe de ser > 0 < 20 ");

}

public float obtenerLongitud()
{
    return longitud;
}

 public float obtenerAnchura()
 {
    return anchura;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tus métodos no les pasas los parámetros necesarios para validar

```
public void establecerLongitud(double longitudPrueba) {
if (longitud >= 0.0 && longitud < 20.0)
 longitud = longitudPrueba;
else
 throw new IllegalArgumentException(
  "la longitud debe debe de ser > 0 < 20.0");
  } // establecerLongitud

 public void establecerAnchura(double anchuraPrueba) {
   if (anchura >= 0.0 && anchura < 20.0)
     anchura = anchuraPrueba;
   else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
 "el ancho debe de ser > 0 < 20 ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solución se me ocurre puede ser la siguiente:

En el constructor, resolví el tema de llamar al `set` (establecer), para validar el *input*.

```
public class Rectangulo {
    private double longuitud, altura;

    public Rectangulo(double longuitud, double altura) {
        this.longuitud = setLonguitud(longuitud);
        this.altura = setAltura(altura);
    }
    public Rectangulo(){
        this.longuitud = 1;
        this.altura = 1;
    }
    public double getLonguitud() {
        return longuitud;
    }

    public double setLonguitud(double longuitud) {

        if (longuitud > 0.0 && longuitud <= 20.0) {
            return longuitud;
        } else {
            return longuitud = 1;
        }

    }

    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }

    public double setAltura(double altura) {
        if (altura > 0.0 && altura <= 20.0){
            return this.altura = altura;
        }else{
            return this.altura = 1;
        }
    }

    public double calcularArea() {
        return getLonguitud() * getAltura();
    }

    public double calcularPerimetro() {

        return 2 * (getLonguitud() + getAltura());
    }

    public String toRectangulo() {
        DecimalFormat dosDigitos = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        return "Longuitud: " + dosDigitos.format(getLonguitud()) + " Altura: "
            + dosDigitos.format(getAltura());
    }

    public String toArea() {
        DecimalFormat dosDigitos = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        return "El area es: " + dosDigitos.format(calcularArea());
    }

    public String toPerimetro() {
        DecimalFormat dosDigitos = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        return "El perimetro es: " + dosDigitos.format(calcularPerimetro());
    }
}
```

... y el *main* para hacer la prueba, sería así:

```
public class PruebaRectangulo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangulo r1 = new Rectangulo(-1, -22.06);
        Rectangulo r2 = new Rectangulo(3.15, 5.15);
        Rectangulo r4 = new Rectangulo(20.5, 0);

        System.out.println("R1");

        r1.calcularArea();
        r1.calcularPerimetro();
        System.out.println(r1.toRectangulo());
        System.out.println(r1.toArea());
        System.out.println(r1.toPerimetro());

        System.out.println("R2");
        r2.calcularArea();
        r2.calcularPerimetro();
        System.out.println(r2.toRectangulo());
        System.out.println(r2.toArea());
        System.out.println(r2.toPerimetro());

        System.out.println("R4");
        r4.calcularArea();
        r4.calcularPerimetro();
        System.out.println(r4.toRectangulo());
        System.out.println(r4.toArea());
        System.out.println(r4.toPerimetro());
    }

}
```